# Python Fibonacci Generator, explain syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found a Python code of Fibonacci Generator, but don't understand all of it. Can some one explain `a, b = b, a + b` line in particulat?

```
a = int(input('Give amount: '))

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fib(a))
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

This line of code works by creating a tuple, and then destructuring it to assign two variables at once. The result is that both `a` and `b` on the left-hand-side are assigned the results of expressions on the right-hand-side which are calculated using the original values of `a` and `b`.

The expression on the right-hand-side is `b, a + b` which is equivalent to `(b, a + b)`, i.e. it creates a tuple with two components.

The assignment target on the left-hand-side is `a, b` which is equivalent to `(a, b)`, i.e. it assigns to two variables simultaneously, using the values of the two components from the tuple respectively. This is called a [destructuring assignment](https://blog.tecladocode.com/destructuring-in-python/).

This is convenient because if the two assignments were written separately, as in the code below, then it would not have the desired effect. The first line changes `a`'s value, and then the *new* value would (incorrectly) be used to calculate `b`:

```py
# WRONG!
a = b
b = a + b
```

Comment: implementation detail: no tuple is actually created in this case, rather, a specialized op code ROT_TWO is used to swap the top two elements in the interpreter stack.

Comment: BUT of course, semantically it is equivalent to creating a tuple and then using destructing assignment on that tuple. And indeed, that's what happens when the tuple display is greater than 3 elements, IIRC

Comment: Interesting and useful to know. Seems like the ROT_TWO shouldn't be necessary for this case because you could just push `b`, then push `a + b`, pop to `b` then pop to `a` (i.e. assign in opposite order). In the general case that wouldn't be equivalent for e.g. `lst[0], lst[0] = x, y`, but for assigning to simple variables this optimisation should be possible for arbitrarily many terms.